# How to invert or complement the output of a function returning Boolean in Java

Tags: java, apache-spark, functional-programming

I'm writing a spark code in java and need to break a dataset in 2 parts . based on some condition.

```
FilterFunction<Row> cond = (Row row) -> {
return true;
}

Dataset<Row> part1 = originalDs.filter(cond ); //This part is easy
Dataset<Row> part2 = originalDs.filter(!cond ); //This part is my problem . Doesn't work
```

Now obviously I can write another filter function which returns `false`, but the inner logic is complicated and I dont want to rewrite same logic and want to use same filter function .

Is there a way in java where I can Wrap this function and somewhat get the complement out put ?

Comment: _need to break a dataset in 2 parts_ => `Collectors::partitioningBy`

Comment: Thanks . That's a good suggestion . But I'll like to know this solution as well, in scala we can use `not functionname` as lambda . How to do that in java ?

Comment: `Predicate::not`, since java-11 or as simple as `a -> !(whatever your condition)`

Comment: :( .. Still on java - 8

Comment: and what is exactly the problem of using that `!`? And you can _always_ get the code from `Predicate::not`, import it to your utilities and use that.

Comment: !filterFunc is invalid syntax in java . `Predicate::not filterfunc` cant call static method from no static context

Comment: how about asking one question at a time?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
Dataset<Row> part1 = originalDs.filter(cond);
Dataset<Row> part2 = originalDs.join(part1, "uniqColOrPrimarykey", "leftanti");
```

`except` won't work if you have to modify `part1` schema . but left-anti join works always.

Left anti join basically keeps the rows in left which are not there in right , hence rightly named as `anti`

Comment: But thanks @Grisha . Your answer finally lead to my solution

Answer (score 1):

You can use [except](https://spark.apache.org/docs/2.3.0/api/java/org/apache/spark/sql/Dataset.html#except-org.apache.spark.sql.Dataset-) function like that

```
Dataset<Row> part1 = originalDs.filter(cond);
Dataset<Row> part2 = originalDs.except(part1);
```

There is one catch here though - `except` also performs `distinct`, which may be useful (or at least harmless) in some cases but not in the others.